# Putting data directly into S3-IA

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I'm having this SAA-C02 question.
[image: S3 question]

It said that the correct response is S3-IA .However,it's impossible to put data directly into S3-IA.In fact,Data must be present a S3 or S3-IT for at least 30 days .After that we can move it to S3-IA.

[image: S3-IA]

Can someone please clarify this issue ?

Comment: By the way, good place for asking aws cert quetions is https://old.reddit.com/r/AWSCertifications/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

30 day rule is for **lifecycles**' automated transitions. From docs:

> Before you transition objects from the S3 Standard or S3 Standard-IA storage classes to S3 Standard-IA or S3 One Zone-IA, you must store them at **least 30 days** in the S3 Standard storage class.

However, you can upload your objects **manually** to any class without needing to wait 30 days. For example using AWS CLI [s3 cp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) you specify that using:

```
--storage-class STANDARD | REDUCED_REDUNDANCY | STANDARD_IA | ONEZONE_IA | INTELLIGENT_TIERING | GLACIER | DEEP_ARCHIVE | GLACIER_IR
```

Answer (score 1):

Agreed, 30 day wait period is for lifecycle transitions and that applies to S3 Standard-IA and S3 One Zone-IA only.